# JSON.php decode behavior different between servers

Tags: php, json

I have the following problem : On my local development server PHP 5.3.10 / Apache 2 every things goes right. When I run the same code with the production server PHP Version 5.2.13 / Apache 2 the code fail but on certain conditions not always.

More details :

The context : I have a dojox.data.grid table on the screen that can be updated. The modified data is correctly passed to the server as a JSON string. Like this :

```
data = {
    "deletedItems":{}
    ,"newItems":{}
    ,"modifiedItems":{
        "2890":{"idFacture":"2890"
                ,"idClient":"175"
            ,"idAffaire":"1323"
            ,"idContrat":"2234"
            ,"raisonSociale":"xxxxxx"
            ,"nomAffaire":"xxxxxx"
            ,"nrFacture":"xxxxx"
            ,"dateFacture":"2012-12-06"
            ,"montantFacture":"160000.00"
            ,"pourcentageFacture":"64.88"
            ,"pourcentageCalcule":"32.44"
            ,"noteFacture":""
            ,"dateTransfert":""
            ,"aTransferer":true
            ,"typeDocument":"Facture"
            ,"factureSoldee":false
            ,"montantTotalHeures":"0.00"
            ,"pourcentageTotalHeures":"0.00"
            ,"montantTotalMateriel":"0.00"
            ,"pourcentageTotalMateriel":"0.00"
            ,"montantTotalSousTraitance":"160000.00"
            ,"pourcentageTotalSousTraitance":"40.94"
    }
    ,"2892":{"idFacture":"2892"
        ,"idClient":"50"
                    ,"idAffaire":"1649"
            ,"idContrat":"2713"
            ,"raisonSociale":"xxxxx"
            ,"nomAffaire":"xxxxx"
            ,"nrFacture":"xxxxx"
            ,"dateFacture":"2012-12-07"
            ,"montantFacture":"12004.50"
            ,"pourcentageFacture":"0.00"
            ,"pourcentageCalcule":"41.94"
            ,"noteFacture":""
            ,"dateTransfert":""
            ,"aTransferer":true
            ,"typeDocument":"Facture"
            ,"factureSoldee":false
            ,"montantTotalHeures":"12004.50"
            ,"pourcentageTotalHeures":"41.95"
            ,"montantTotalMateriel":"0.00"
            ,"pourcentageTotalMateriel":"0.00"
            ,"montantTotalSousTraitance":"0.00"
            ,"pourcentageTotalSousTraitance":"0.00"
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that the data contains three elements "deletedItems" (empty), "createdItems" (empty) and "modifiedItems".

In the php code i have the following commands :

```
$srvJson = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);

$data = $srvJson->decode($data);
```

Where $data is filled like above. Normally after that last statement the folowing PHP variables are set :

- $data["deletedItems"]
- $data["createdItems"]
- $data["modifiedItems"]

Here is the problem : if on the production server there are a lot of modified rows (about > 30) in the table, the modified data is correctly passed to the serveur BUT $data["modifiedItems"] is not set ??? If I just modify the dataset for a few rows $data["modifiedItems"] is well set.
I can modify the whole data set piece per piece, but not the whole dataset in one time.

I suppose this is a question of server settings but what ?

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Best regards,

Roger

PS : Sorry for my english

Comment: Since both installs are > 5.2.0, you can use the built in json_decode.  Anyway, that's not valid JSON.  Not sure how Services_JSON works, but I'm assuming that it expects valid JSON.

Comment: This would be valid JSON if you get rid of everything before the first `{` and after the last `}`.

Comment: I am sorry but this is not a question of valid JSON or not. This JSON is valid. The issue is in a difference between the two servers.

Comment: No, no it's not.  `data = ` makes it invalid.  That's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: OK, sorry, "data" is the name of the post variable. The variable content begin's at the first "{"

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not valid JSON (checked with http://jsonlint.com/) the results of json_decode() in PHP 5.3.10 and PHP 5.2.13 are different!

While 5.3 returns nothing 5.2.13 returns the initial string. Probably your code has somewhere some error corrections...

See the different results of the different PHP version on [**3v4l.org**](http://3v4l.org/ffYj4)!

When us remove `data =` from your JSON [does not throw errors.](http://3v4l.org/sv4X4).

Comment: data is the name of the post variable. This not part of the json string.

Comment: Thanks powtac for your answer. data is the name of the post variable. This not part of the json string. What is surprising is that the code runs well on both server IF i modify only a few rows in the table. If "modifiedItems" contains more than about 30 items the code don't decode "modifiedItems".

Comment: @Roger Ok, you might update the JSON string example in the question. Have a look in your PHP error log maybe there is a notice about a memory problem ("~ more than 30 items")

Answer (score 0):

Based on your above issue, you can check following things on server

- magic_quotes are open or closed on server similiar to local server
- Does Services_JSON is compitable to PHP 5.3
- Services_JSON is pear php library so please check that it is working properly with all extension of php
  http://pear.php.net/bugs/search.php?cmd=display&package_name%5B%5D=Services_JSON

Or you can use the default php json library for encode and decode

May this will help you

Comment: Thanks Harsh Chunara. See the answer I made to powtac above.

Comment: Thanks Harsh Chunara. See the answer I made to powtac above. I can assure you that the code runs well on both PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3. The magic_quotes parameter is the same on both servers. I am using Services_JSON in a lot of my PHP programs on these server without any problem. This is just a question that when the "modifieditems" element contains a lot (about > 30) it goes wrong, If the numbre of item is less it runs well. I thought first it was a question of data in the string but it if not. I can process the whole data table 30 items by 30 items until i reach the end of it without problem